# Problem after I changed developer mode

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, developer-mode, frontend-error, production-mode

after I change from default to  developer mode my homepage is look like this

[image]

what is my mistake ?  please help me

Comment: A server 500 error usually has additional information available in your server's error log (apache2 or nginx are the most common ones). That error message should help in troubleshooting this issue - without knowing anything further my guess is on a permission problem.

Comment: add ini_set("display_errors",1);  index.php header then you can able to see errors

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines to your .htaccess file

```
php_flag display_startup_errors on
php_flag display_errors on
php_flag html_errors on
```

Then make sure all permissions are correct on var/ and pub/ (if it is a dev system you could just give 777 on var/ and pub/ DO NOT DO THIS ON PRODUCTION)